# Add permissions to an Azure application by using the .net SDK

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to automate Application creation on Azure, I've been searching the .Net SDK, but couldn't find **how to add permissions to a new\existing Application**.

I was able to find the equivalent cli commands for what I'm trying to do:

`az ad app permission add --id {APPLICATION_ID} --api 00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --api-permissions c5366453-9fb0-48a5-a156-24f0c49a4b84=Scope`

(c5366453-9fb0-48a5-a156-24f0c49a4b84 is Directory.ReadWrite.All)

For the record, I'm creating the Application with the following C# command:

```
var appRegistrationRes = await graphService.Applications.Define($"My App")
    .WithSignOnUrl("https://my-site-url.com/")
    .DefinePasswordCredential("password")
        .WithPasswordValue(password)
        .WithDuration(TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 10))
        .Attach()
    .WithAvailableToOtherTenants(false)
    .CreateAsync();
```

Comment: Assigning permissions is done to the application service principal, not the Application object. Maybe there is some methods in that library to modify "oauth2PermissionGrants" on the service principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegated

[Create a delegated permission grant (oAuth2PermissionGrant)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/oauth2permissiongrant-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Application

[Grant an appRoleAssignment for a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-post-approleassignedto?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: Hi, I have created an app called API and inside Manifest I have created app roles and in "expose an API" i have created a scope (which is delegated permission)...Now I am creating another app using graph API and I want to give application permission and delegate permission to that app...Do you know some link which I can refer to?